# how to configure Yi 0.14.0

Tags: haskell

```
apt-get install yi
```

Yi works，yi test.hs will load ~/.config/yi/yi.hs

```
cabal install yi
```

Yi don't load the configure file, why? who to setup

Comment: Yi 0.14.0 doesn't support dynamic configuration out of the box any more. See [Yi blog post](https://yi-editor.github.io/posts/2017-07-25-release-0.14/). You probably want to try [yi-dynamic-configuration](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yi-dynamic-configuration)